# How to pass a static method to a constant constructor?

Tags: dart

[Docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#class-variables-and-methods) says

> You can use static methods as compile-time constants. For example, you can pass a static method as a parameter to a constant constructor.

But when I tried doing that, I get an error:

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
class Foo {
  const Foo(int x);
}

class Bar {
  static int get x => 0;
  void m() => const Foo(Bar.x); // Error
}
```

Comment: `static int get x => 0;` <-- This declares a static property-getter, not a static method.

Comment: @Dai Try with`static int getX() => 0;` which is a static method and you'll still have the same error.

Comment: because you're passing an int, NOT a function, change it to function instead of int and let Foo constructor accept Function

Comment: @Nagual Thanks, that actually answers the question. You can write it in answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Nagual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74010702/how-to-pass-a-static-method-to-a-constant-constructor/74011254#comment130678167_74010702) for pointing out the mistake. I was actually *calling* the method (and passing `int`) instead of *passing* the method itself.

This is what I should have done:

```dart
class Foo {
  const Foo(int Function() cb);
}

class Bar {
  static int getX() => 0;
  void m() => const Foo(Bar.getX); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the documentation more literally:

> You can use static **methods** as compile-time constants. For example, you can pass a **static method** as **a parameter** to a constant constructor.

Emphasis mine. What that means is:

```
class Foo {
  const Foo(void Function() func);
}

class Bar {
  static void barMethod() {}
}

void main() {
  final foo = Foo(Bar.barMethod);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it was explained in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74010702/how-to-pass-a-static-method-to-a-constant-constructor/74011254#comment130678167_74010702). I was actually *calling* the method instead of *passing* it directly.